# LOGIN Button greyed out on Execution of Script WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById

Tags: vb.net

This code used to work. After an upgrade I cannot use it anymore as the loginbutton remains greyed out:

```
 WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Username").Focus();
 WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Username").InnerText = "trainingw2k19\\Lenka";
 WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Password").Focus();
 WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Password").InnerText = "ww";
 WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("submitLogin").Focus();
 WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("submitLogin").InvokeMember("Click");
```

Is there anyone who has the same issue?
The element in the actual webinterface:

```
<div id="logininputFields">
    <div class="login-form-group">
        <label class="login-control-label from-control-label" for="LoginUsername">User name</label>
        <input name="Username" title="Please type your username" id="LoginUsername" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Please type your username" value="">
        <i class="loginbar"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="login-form-group password-div" style="display: block;">
        <label class="login-control-label from-control-label" for="LoginPassword">Password</label>
        <input name="Password" title="Please type your password" id="LoginPassword" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Please type your password">
        <i class="loginbar"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Black cat, just noticed the portion of the button is not inserted:

Comment: <div id="loginButton">
                                <button title="Sign In" class="ads-typography--button loginbutton wwButton wwButtonCustom" id="submitLogin" style="display: block;" onclick="return LogonAIM();">
                                    <span>Sign In</span>

Comment: The username and password are correct filled in, it is the Sign in, ID = submitlogon which is not activated in the .net Control webbrowser

Comment: The code was from the one which is working, actual is:

'WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Username").Focus();
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("LoginUsername").InnerText = "trainingw2k19\Lenka";
'WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Password").Focus();
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("LoginPassword").InnerText = "ww";

When I click in the name and remove one letter and add it again then the Sign In button is enabled. Using the script again at that moment works. Seems to be a focus problem.